# Solve the differential equation $(2x^2+3y^2-7)x\mathrm{d}x - (3x^2+2y^2-8)y\mathrm{d}y = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:

**Solve the differential equation**
$$(2x^2+3y^2-7)x\mathrm{d}x - (3x^2+2y^2-8)y\mathrm{d}y = 0$$

My attempt:
$$(2x^2+3y^2-7)x\mathrm{d}x - (3x^2+2y^2-8)y\mathrm{d}y = 0$$
Let $$u = x^2 +y^2 -3$$
$$2u = 2x^2+2y^2-6$$
so,
$$2x^2+3y^2-6= 2u +(y^2-1)$$
and
$$3x^2+2y^2-8 = 3u-(y^2-1)$$
so,
$$\frac{x}{y} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{3u-(y^2-1)}{2u+(y^2-1)}$$
To convert the equation into variables $u$ and $y$,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^2+y^2-3)}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y}= 2x \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}+2y$$

Solving for $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{1}{2x}\biggr(\frac{\mathrm{d}u}
{\mathrm{d}y}-2y\biggr)$$
Plugging in the problem
$$\frac{x}{y}\cdot\frac{1}{2x}\biggr(\frac{\mathrm{d}u}
{\mathrm{d}y}-2y\biggr)=  \frac{3u-(y^2-1)}{2u+(y^2-1)}$$
Upon solving,
$$\frac{1}{2y}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}
{\mathrm{d}y}=  \frac{5u}{2u+(y^2-1)}$$
Moreover, let
$$t = y^2-1$$
$$\mathrm{d}t= 2y\mathrm{d}y$$
Plug in the above equation (ambiguous step?),
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{5u}{2u+t}$$
Even now, I can't separate the variables.

All suggestions are welcome. Please attempt to provide alternate solutions. Thanks!